# Use vim in bash script to replace characters

Tags: macos, bash, vim

I want to build a small util script that will replace characters in a given file. Here's what I have so far. When I run this, I see my echo messages, but the program never returns. If I manually exit the program, there is no effect. So it seems it is hanging somewhere, but I can't be sure why.

```
sEnv=$1
eEnv=$2
reverseArgs=$3
echo ${reverseArgs}
if [ "$3" == "-r" ]; then
   echo "changing from ${eEnv} to ${sEnv}"
   cmd="vim -E -s /Users/X/nginx.conf << EOF\
   :%s/${eEnv}/${sEnv}/g\
   :wq\
   EOF"
   `${cmd}`
else
   echo "changing from ${sEnv} to ${eEnv}"
   cmd="vim -E -s /Users/X/nginx.conf << EOF\
   :%s/${sEnv}/${eEnv}/g\
   :wq\
   EOF"
   `${cmd}`
fi
EOF
```

I know it is supposed to work, because if I just put this in my script it works:

```
vim -E -s /Users/X/nginx.conf << EOF
   :%s/${eEnv}/${sEnv}/g
   :wq
   EOF
```

Comment: Why not use `sed`?

Comment: How would that look like ? I need to be able to pass parameters to the script

Comment: @QuantumLicht sed/awk can accept parameters.

Comment: Accepting the option only *after* the parameters is un-Unixy.

Comment: @tripleee, what would be the correct way to pass the params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure why you go via variable cmd. Try:

```
sEnv=$1
eEnv=$2
reverseArgs=$3
echo ${reverseArgs}
if [ "$3" == "-r" ]; then
   echo "changing from ${eEnv} to ${sEnv}"
   vim -E -s - /Users/X/nginx.conf <<EOF
   :%s/${eEnv}/${sEnv}/g
   :wq
EOF
else
   echo "changing from ${sEnv} to ${eEnv}"
   vim -E -s - /Users/philippeguay/nginx.conf <<EOF
   :%s/${sEnv}/${eEnv}/g
   :wq
EOF
fi
```

I added `-s -` for my vim else it takes the filename as a script, I think.
Note the EOF must not be indented.

Answer (score 3):

As @trojanfoe first suggested, you should use `sed` for a job like this.  It's better suited:

```
sed -i "s/${eEnv}/${sEnv}/g" ${file}
```

It would be possible to do it with `vim`, though.  The reason your attempt does not work is that you are building the command to execute as a string, and in doing so, crushing your heredoc into an ordinary string.  I don't see why that's useful, when you could just execute the command directly:

```
vim -E -s /Users/philippeguay/nginx.conf << EOF
:%s/${sEnv}/${eEnv}/g
:wq
EOF
```

Comment: Agreed, the only reason I wanted a script is to add a flag to switch the arguments without having to rewrite the args in the command line. Call me lazy, but that's the only reason really. Can sed do that ?

Comment: @QuantumLicht, I am not questioning your use of a script.  That's an appropriate means to select whether to do the forward or the reverse command.  I am questioning your choice of `vim` over `sed`.  I like `vim` for *interactive* editing, but `sed` is the conventional choice for use in a script.

Comment: Ahhh... Thanks for the clarification. It makes indeed much sense. Thanks for the input! I will try it out with `sed`. I will still leave the @meuh answer as the accepted answer, because it worked out of the box with minimal change to my code.